# PHP. Remove Links from Strings

Tags: php, string, replace

Helllo, I have some user-generated content on the website. I want to remove links out of it using php functions.

For example I have the following string:

```
"text1 http://link1 text2 www.link2 text3 link3.com text4"
```

Is there a simple way to detect words, containing http:, www., .com and to remove them from text? Or is there any other good way of cleaning the text from links?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$pattern = "/[a-zA-Z]*[:\/\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+/i";
$replacement = "";
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Works well for basic simple URLs. When the URLs contain special characters such as { or }, it fails. But it's great for removal of SEO friendly links.

Answer (score 5):

Oh, I found the answer.

```
function cleaner($url) {
  $U = explode(' ',$url);

  $W =array();
  foreach ($U as $k => $u) {
if (stristr($u,'http') || (count(explode('.',$u)) > 1)) {
  unset($U[$k]);
  return cleaner( implode(' ',$U));
}
}
  return implode(' ',$U);
}

$url = "Here is another funny site www.tinyurl.com/55555 and http://www.tinyurl.com/55555 and img.hostingsite.com/badpic.jpg";
echo "Cleaned: " . cleaner($url);
```